# Видео с youtube бэкграундом на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать видео бэкграундом с youtube, с фиксированной высотой без ущерба ширине? Чтобы было адаптивно.

Comment: http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Answer (score 3):

Вот работающий пример. ID видео добавляется непосредственно в скрипт. Можно задать несколько видео, время старта и окончания.

http://codepen.io/pen/KrmdAG

Отредактируете класс .cover под ваши нужды, задав ему позицию relative и высоту с фиксированным значением, и готово.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/player_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var tv,
  playerDefaults = {autoplay: 0, autohide: 1, modestbranding: 0, rel: 0, showinfo: 0, controls: 0, disablekb: 1, enablejsapi: 0, iv_load_policy: 3};
var vid = [
   {'videoId': 'iNJdPyoqt8U', 'startSeconds': 15, 'endSeconds': 290, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
   {'videoId': '0wCC3aLXdOw', 'startSeconds': 465, 'endSeconds': 657, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'}
  ],
  randomvid = Math.floor(Math.random() * (vid.length - 1 + 1));

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){
  tv = new YT.Player('tv', {events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
}

function onPlayerReady(){
  tv.loadVideoById(vid[randomvid]);
  tv.mute();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
  if (e.data === 1){
    $('#tv').addClass('active');
  } else if (e.data === 0){
    tv.seekTo(vid[randomvid].startSeconds)
  }
}

function vidRescale(){

  var w = $(window).width()+200,
    h = $(window).height()+200;

  if (w/h > 16/9){
    tv.setSize(w, w/16*9);
    $('.tv .screen').css({'left': '0px'});
  } else {
    tv.setSize(h/9*16, h);
    $('.tv .screen').css({'left': -($('.tv .screen').outerWidth()-w)/2});
  }
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  vidRescale();
});

$('.hi span').on('click', function(){
  $('#tv').toggleClass('mute');
  if($('#tv').hasClass('mute')){
    tv.mute();
  } else {
    tv.unMute();
  }
});
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:100,300,300italic,500,500italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic";
body {
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Exo 2',sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #ff0;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.cover .hi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cover .hi span {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.tv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tv .screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.tv .screen.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="hi">Тут может быть расположен ваш контент</div>
</div>
<div class="tv"><div class="screen mute" id="tv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё довольно просто, ставите html код на вашей странице:

```
<div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И соотвецтвенно стиль для ваших классов:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```