# Формат видео для фона сайта

Tags: html, css, оптимизация

Какой формат видео лучше всего выбирать для фона на сайт, чтобы соотношение вес/качество был самым оптимальным?
Сейчас стоит mp4, 720p качество. 37 секунд 11МБ

Хочется все это оптимизировать.

Comment: Посмотреть можешь на сайтах, где уже стоит это

Comment: 11М - это перебор. Рекомендуют не более 1М.
Если это видео 37 секунд - я бы предложил оформить его в виде плеера. Таким образом мы дадим пользователю выбор - скачивать или нет 11М.

Answer (score 3):

Небольшой лайфхак. Загрузите видео на YouTube, после чего скачайте оттуда пережатый файл. Вес будет намного меньше исходного. 11Мб - очень много, еще в 3-4Мб можно пробовать поставить (но, и это много).

Так же подойдет вариант с использованием плеера. Вот там [готовый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539650/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D1%81-youtube-%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5/539996#539996).